# DISM: Why am I getting Error: 2, unable to access the image

Tags: windows, image, cmd, dism

After mounting a image to my local C drive in the folder 'mount', I run the command:

```
dism /image:c:\mount /get-features
```

I receive an error message:

```
Error: 2

Unable to access the image.
Make sure that the image path and the windows directory for the image exist and you have Read permissions on the folder.
```

I've looked far and wide on the internet and have failed to find an answer.
Under security settings on the mount folder, all users for the machine have full read access. Anybody know what the Issue is?

I understand this is not exactly programming, but thought I'd ask here anyhow.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved the issue using start up repair to get to the dos prompt and then  by navigating in DOS back to my OS drive as that is where the image is 
in my case my O/S drive is C:\ and my new drivers were on a thumb drive in a folder called Drivers
in my case the command was 
C:\dism /image:c:\ /add-driver /Driver:e:\Drivers\ /recurse

Comment: I'm no longer able to try the solution. If somebody lets me know if this works, I'll make accept this answer.